# Is there a generalized equation for a line in barycentric coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, barycentric-coordinates

I've read that in the plane the equation for points $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ on the line passing through $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)$ and $\nu=(\nu_1,\nu_2,\nu_3)$ is
$$
  \left|\begin{array} \\
    \mu_1 & \mu_2 & \mu_3 \\
    \nu_1 & \nu_2 & \nu_3 \\
    \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3
  \end{array}\right|=0
$$
And I want a formula that generalizes this to higher dimensions. It seems most natural to assume that the generalization is
$$\mu\wedge\nu\wedge\lambda=0$$
If this is the case I'd like hints on how to prove it, otherwise I'd just like to know whether or not a neat generalization exists and what it is.